# Dismiss UISwipeActionsConfiguration on reloading the table

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiswipeactionsconfiguration

When user swipe the cell I m showing some option. Everything is working fine, When user scroll the table swipe option goes off. I want the same behaviour when I reload the table on data change. How to achieve that. If user has swipe the cell and I reload table , Swipe options are still there.

Comment: Please add some code, what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You hide the swiped cell just add this line of code before reloading the table view.

```
tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
```

Now for enabling the editing, In your cellForAtIndex Path function make a check like

```
if indexPath.row == array.size {
   tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)
}
```